# is there AES source code (VB.NET) that decrypts AS3CRYPTO crypted msgs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encryption

Is there a simple ASP.NET (.VB) available for AES-encrypting?

here is a link to c# one but its complicate one having pretty much parameters, for example salt. 
[http://www.gutgames.com/post/AES-Encryption-in-C.aspx]

I need a simple one that works together with GOOGLEAS3 Class that is called easily like this:

```
var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray("1234567890abcdef");
var pt:ByteArray = Hex.toArray( Hex.fromString("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"));
var aes:AESKey = new AESKey(key);
aes.encrypt(pt);
var out:String = Hex.fromArray(pt).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES is built into the framework, as the [Aes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) class in System.Security.Cryptography. There are two concrete implementations, one managed, one using the Windows Crypto Service Provider (faster, but not portable to other platforms). There's also an implementation of [Rijndael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx), from which AES derives.

Remember you need an initialization vector, as well as the key to encrypt/decrypt, as it's a block cipher. If you encrypt without setting one a random one will be used, but you will need to store and retrieve it for decryption.

Example Code: (lifted from chapter 6 of my forthcoming book *grin*)

```
static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] clearText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    // Create an instance of our encyrption algorithm.
    RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

    // Create an encryptor using our key and IV
    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

    // Create the streams for input and output
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream inputStream = new CryptoStream(
        outputStream,
        transform,
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Feed our data into the crypto stream.
    inputStream.Write(clearText, 0, clearText.Length);

    // Flush the crypto stream.
    inputStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // And finally return our encrypted data.
    return outputStream.ToArray();
}
```

and to decrypt

```
static byte[] Decyrpt(byte[] clearText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    // Create an instance of our encryption algorithm.
    RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

    // Create an decryptor using our key and IV
    ICryptoTransform transform = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

    // Create the streams for input and output
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream inputStream = new CryptoStream(
        outputStream,
        transform,
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    // Feed our data into the crypto stream.
    inputStream.Write(clearText, 0, clearText.Length);

    // Flush the crypto stream.
    inputStream.FlushFinalBlock();

    // And finally return our decrypted data.
    return outputStream.ToArray();
}
```

replace the RijndaelManaged class with one of the AES classes and a suitable key.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, and I keep getting a key size violation. Here's my key:
string verySecureKey = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";

When I do:
var algo = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged();
keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(verySecureKey);
algo.Key = keyArray;

I get a key violation on the last line (64 bit instead of 32) - but this works fine in AS3Crypto. Thoughts?